# Remove indent of paragraph after question in exam document class

Tags: indentation, exam

I'd like to remove the indentation that appears before the question content.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\pointname{\ p}
\qformat{\textbf{Question \thequestion .} \hfill \textsl{(\thepoints)}} 

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
  
  \question[3] What is your favourite color?
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

and I'd like something like that

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [`exam`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/exam) documentation, page 33, you need to add the following code to your preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
\setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
\setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
}
```

Then you get the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\pointname{\ p}
\qformat{\textbf{Question \thequestion .} \hfill \textsl{(\thepoints)}} 
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
\setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
\setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question[3] What is your favourite color?

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```